# Joomla JFactory query to return results after today's date

Tags: mysql, joomla

I'm trying to retrieve data from my Joomla! database, but I only want to return results after today (future dates). I've been trying the following, but it isn't working:

```
        ->select('*')
        ->from($params->get('table'))
        ->where('state = 1')
        ->where('eventdate' > date('Y-m-d'))
        ->order('eventdate');
```

What do I need to change?

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer.

```
        ->select('*')
        ->from($params->get('table'))
        ->where('state = 1')
        ->where('eventdate >= CURDATE()')
        ->order('eventdate');
```